# available tools to measure JSF applications performance

Tags: performance, jsf, jakarta-ee, performance-testing, jsf-2.2

What are the available tools that could be used to measure the performance of a web applications developed by JSF framework . Free and open source tools are preferred.

**Target environment:**

Any Java EE full application server. (ex: Glassfish or Wildfly)

We are evaluating the performance of the JSF implementation and the application as a whole.

Comment: What is the target Enviorment? Are we talking about a Full Java-EE compliant Server or a simple WebServer Servlet Container such as Tomcat/Jetty. Also are you evaluating the performance of the JSF implementation or your application as a whole?

Comment: Thanks @dngfng I have edited my questions.

Comment: jmc is a good option, here how to configure it with wildfly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56207317/connect-java-mission-control-to-wildfly-16

Answer (score 2):

[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) would be my tool of choice, its an automated browser that can be used for [load testing](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/selenium-webdriver.html).

Comment: Selenium is not 'automated browser' but can 'automate browser actions'. Also it is not load testing tool. It is highly resource intensive - although you can use cloud service providers who can spin up loads of them for you for $$

Comment: Selenium is not a tool for performance testing. As it is stated in the documentation: "Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results." Look here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/performance_testing/