# Connect Java Mission Control to Wildfly 16

Tags: java, wildfly, jmc

I try to connect Java Mission Control (JMC) with [Wildfly](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly) 16. Application server lays on Docker.

I successfully connected to wildfly via jconsole, to manage it I followed steps described [here](https://www.perftactique.com/2017/03/11/how-to-activate-jmx-access-to-wildfly-using-jconsole-and-hp-sitescope/).

Unfortunately, I have no luck to connect via JMC. The URL which I use looks like this:

> service:jmx:remoting-jmx://192.168.99.100:9990

- I tried to set Xbootclasspath to jboss-cli-client.jar as it was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750032/how-to-connect-to-remote-wildfly-using-jmc), but I just get `Unable to connect` error.
- I set the same jars, which are used for jconsole, but still I got `Unable to connect`.
- I gave a try to adding flags on container site, as it was shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work), but with these flags, even wildfly haven't started.

Then, I found [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2592885?start=0&tstart=0) the idea to hardcode some jboss classes to enable connection via remoting-jmx. I changed version of jars, according to these provided by wildfly16 and put it to jmc.ini like this.

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-10.0.2/lib/missioncontrol/dropins/jboss-cli-client.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/remoting-jmx/main/remoting-jmx-3.0.1.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/remoting/main/jboss-remoting-5.0.8.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logging/main/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/xnio/main/xnio-api-3.6.5.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/xnio/nio/main/xnio-nio-3.6.5.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/marshalling/main/jboss-marshalling-2.0.6.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/marshalling/river/main/jboss-marshalling-river-2.0.6.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/cli/main/wildfly-cli-8.0.0.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/staxmapper/main/staxmapper-1.3.0.Final;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/protocol/main/wildfly-protocol-8.0.0.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/dmr/main/jboss-dmr-1.5.0.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/controller-client/main/wildfly-controller-client-8.0.0.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/threads/main/jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final.jar;C:/wildfly-16.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.1.7.Final.jar"
```

After that, finally, I have another error, which is

> Could not initialize class org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector

I added dependencies of `remoting-jmx-3.0.1.Final` to Xbootclasspath, but I got still the same error.

My question is, have you got any idea, how to make this connection works ? Maybe someone have done it in different way ?

Any advices how can i debug this problem, will be priceless? Because I'm lack of ideas how to solve it.

Comment: I normally take a copy of the jconsole script and then update for jmc. As you have found, the parameter to set the classpath is different, but the jars used are the same

Comment: @WillT Do you have any example ?

Comment: `jmc -cp...`will not work. Does any of these links help? - https://community.oracle.com/thread/2592885?tstart=0 - http://sattish-performanceengg.blogspot.com/2016/01/configure-java-mission-control-for.html  - https://gautric.github.io/blog/2016/07/19/JConsole-JavaMissionControl-JBoss-EAP-7.html - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/700283

Comment: @Klara Finnaly I was able to setup this connection, I done it by usage of the jmc from jdk 8, as all tutorials refers to this older jmc. I can't find any way to do it for higher versions :(

Comment: @MyWay Which JMC version/build are you using? I assume this is on Windows?

Comment: @Klara JMC 6 from jdk 1.8.0_121. Yes, I did it on windows. I described here ( https://github.com/ThisIsMyWay/BookShopProject ), how I was able to connect it,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In %WILDFLY_HOME%\bin\standalone.conf.bat
   put:

   set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+FlightRecorder"
2. In jmc.ini  below -vmargs put

   -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\%wildfly_home%\bin\client\jboss-cli-client.jar

(%wildfly_home% is different of course, or just copy jboss-cli-client.jar to another directory and correct the path)
3. Run JMC, then Create New Connection - in Connection Properties pane push the button "Custom JMX service URL", put:

```
service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://localhost:9990
```

In the credentials fields just put user and password, they should be created for Realm Management (e.g. using %wildfly_home%\bin\add-user.bat)
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks It help me a lot. Of Course there is no need to emphasis restarting JMC but I forgot it and had trouble some more minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I also added -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures in addition to -XX:+FlightRecorder

Comment: Works fine. But only on Java 8. Java 11 fails.

Answer (score 1):

Solution doesn't work on java 11 for me. Mission control fails on connect to wildfly with error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ietf/jgss/GSSManager
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
at java.base/java.security.Provider.newInstanceUtil(Provider.java:152)
at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1824)
at org.wildfly.security.WildFlyElytronBaseProvider$ProviderService.newInstance(WildFlyElytronBaseProvider.java:218)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.SecurityProviderSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(SecurityProviderSaslClientFactory.java:94)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.ProtocolSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(ProtocolSaslClientFactory.java:50)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.ServerNameSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(ServerNameSaslClientFactory.java:50)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.ServerNameSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(ServerNameSaslClientFactory.java:50)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.FilterMechanismSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(FilterMechanismSaslClientFactory.java:102)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.LocalPrincipalSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(LocalPrincipalSaslClientFactory.java:76)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.PrivilegedSaslClientFactory.lambda$createSaslClient$0(PrivilegedSaslClientFactory.java:64)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.PrivilegedSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(PrivilegedSaslClientFactory.java:64)
at org.wildfly.security.auth.client.AuthenticationConfiguration.createSaslClient(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:1545)
at org.wildfly.security.auth.client.AuthenticationContextConfigurationClient.createSaslClient(AuthenticationContextConfigurationClient.java:430)
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:419)
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:244)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
```

Besides, jmc that was embedded to jdk 8 isn't able to start flight recording for java 11 process.
So after investigation i found out that this class is loaded with bootstrap classloader. According to https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261
jdk.security.jgss module isn't defined to bootstrap classloader. But classes in jboss-cli-client.jar(it originates from wildfly-elytron project) need jgss  classes in runtime.
So i found out dirty workaround for this problem: bootstrap needed classes from jre 8 in jmc.ini. Full option for linux is:

```
-vmargs -Xbootclasspath/a:<path_to_wildfly>/jboss-cli-client.jar:<path_to_jdk8>/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

And for windows:

```
-vmargs -Xbootclasspath/a:<path_to_wildfly>\jboss-cli-client.jar;<path_to_jdk8>\jre\lib\rt.jar
```

after this jmc(run on 11 jdk) succesfully connects to wildfly(run on 11 jdk) and can start and analyze flight recordings.

Comment: Altering the boot classpath in such a way may have side effects. I suggest to stick with Java and Java Mission Control versions which work together. The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76572799/345057 outlines the approach.