# Java Mission Control 7 running on Java 11 cannot connect to Wildfly with "jmx:remoting-jmx" protocol

Tags: java, wildfly, java-11, jmc, jfr

As far as I can tell, I am having the same issue described here:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/278895

(That forum is closed and no additional comments are allowed, their recommendation is to post to SO)

I am trying to run JMC 7.1.2 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.8.10.1 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode) on my workstation and connect to a remote Wildfly server using the "jmx:remoting-jmx" protocol. This worked for years, but AFAICT does not work in the constellation Java-11 and JMC7.

There is no error about unknown protocol or similar
(Yes, I have already read and followed instructions in:
[Connect Java Mission Control to Wildfly 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56207317/connect-java-mission-control-to-wildfly-16)), but I get this error when connecting:

```
org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.ConnectionException caused by javax.security.sasl.SaslException: org/ietf/jgss/GSSManager [Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ietf/jgss/GSSManager]
    at org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.internal.RJMXConnection.connect(RJMXConnection.java:441)
    at org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.internal.ServerHandle.doConnect(ServerHandle.java:116)
    at org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.internal.ServerHandle.connect(ServerHandle.java:106)
    at org.openjdk.jmc.console.ui.editor.internal.ConsoleEditor$ConnectJob.run(ConsoleEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: org/ietf/jgss/GSSManager [Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ietf/jgss/GSSManager]
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:426)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:242)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:599)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:561)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:549)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalRemotingConnect(RemotingConnector.java:268)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalConnect(RemotingConnector.java:156)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.connect(RemotingConnector.java:103)
    at org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.internal.RJMXConnection.connectJmxConnector(RJMXConnection.java:487)
    at org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.internal.RJMXConnection.establishConnection(RJMXConnection.java:464)
    at org.openjdk.jmc.rjmx.internal.RJMXConnection.connect(RJMXConnection.java:434)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ietf/jgss/GSSManager
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider.newInstanceUtil(Provider.java:153)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1891)
    at org.wildfly.security.WildFlyElytronBaseProvider$ProviderService.newInstance(WildFlyElytronBaseProvider.java:218)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.SecurityProviderSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(SecurityProviderSaslClientFactory.java:94)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.ProtocolSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(ProtocolSaslClientFactory.java:50)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.ServerNameSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(ServerNameSaslClientFactory.java:50)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.ServerNameSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(ServerNameSaslClientFactory.java:50)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.FilterMechanismSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(FilterMechanismSaslClientFactory.java:102)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(AbstractDelegatingSaslClientFactory.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.LocalPrincipalSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(LocalPrincipalSaslClientFactory.java:76)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.PrivilegedSaslClientFactory.lambda$createSaslClient$0(PrivilegedSaslClientFactory.java:64)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.PrivilegedSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(PrivilegedSaslClientFactory.java:64)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.client.AuthenticationConfiguration.createSaslClient(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:1496)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.client.AuthenticationContextConfigurationClient.createSaslClient(AuthenticationContextConfigurationClient.java:408)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:420)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:242)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
```

If I use OpenJDK 8 with JMC 7 then it works (that is, I can connect and also read jfr files created with jdk11) but is that really the only way to get this configuration to work?

Comment: Have you checked if your Corretto JDK contains the module jdk.security.jgss at all?

Comment: yes it does jdk.security.jgss.jmod

Comment: Maybe an issue with the version you are using?

Comment: Same issue here. Only works on Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and found a solution by putting together the following pieces. From the Oracle documentation:

> JDK Mission Control (JMC) 8.0 and 8.0.1 starts with Oracle JDK 8 (64-bit), and from JMC 8.1.0 onwards it requires Oracle JDK 11 and later. However, JMC 8 supports Java Management Console (JMX) monitoring and Java Flight Recorder (JFR) profiling of JVMs (JDK 7u40 and later) on any supported platform.

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jmc8-install.html

For a working configuration, we will need JDK 8. And because we will be running JDK 8, we will need an old version of the JDK mission control.

Thus, we will avoid `NoClassDefFoundError: org/ietf/jgss/GSSManager`, because JDK 8 puts the class on the classpath by default.

#### Step 1: Grab JDK 8

Download and install JDK 8 on your machine. I got it working with Eclipse Temurin.

#### Step 2: Download Java Mission Control 8.0.0

We need to find a distributor of the Java Mission Control. I went with Eclipse Mission Control. Find older releases, which still work with Java 8, on the following channels:

- https://github.com/adoptium/jmc-build/releases/tag/8.0.0
- https://adoptium.net/de/jmc/

#### Step 3: Configure Java Mission Control

We need to instruct JMC to use the Java 8, and add the additional JAR from Wildfly.

Locate `jmc.ini`, and put the following lines in:

The `-vm` parameter, followed by newline, followed by the path of the JDK you just downloaded:

```
-vm
/path/to/your/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/bin
```

Second, a VM option to include the Wildfly JAR:

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:/path/to/your/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/bin/client/jboss-client.jar
```

Change the path names to match your local configuration, and insert the `-vm` parameter *above* `-vmargs`!

The following config file shows a full example of `jmc.ini`:

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.800.v20200727-1323.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.1300.v20200819-0940
--launcher.appendVmargs
-ws
cocoa
-vm
/path/to/your/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-1.8.0_362/Contents/Home/bin
-vmargs
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+DebugNonSafepoints
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=stackdepth=128
-XX:+FlightRecorder
-XX:StartFlightRecording=name=JMC_Default,maxsize=100m
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
--add-exports=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.management/sun.management.counter.perf=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dsun.java.command=JMC
--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.lwawt.macosx=ALL-UNNAMED
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Xbootclasspath/a:/path/to/your/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/bin/client/jboss-client.jar
```

#### Connect

Now we should be able to connect using a URL like `service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://localhost:9990`, and with the credentials of a Wildfly management user.